# Accessing local network from a different network using cloud server

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, vpn, tunneling

I'm not sure if this title is correct, but I have an OpenVPN server on an AWS EC2 instance that I want to use to ssh into my local network machines when I'm on a different network.

A simple method I've thought of that wouldn't really involve port-forwarding (I opened ports on my network machines anyways) would be to ssh to the EC2 instance, then somehow ssh to the computer on my home network connected to my VPN.

I'm a little stuck on how to do this though. Is it possible to ssh from a cloud server to a local network machine (that I've used to ssh from local to cloud before)? If so do I need to forward ssh traffic from a port on my public IP?

From what I've looked up, this seems similar to a "jump server" or bastion host, but I'm unsure how to set this up.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy. Both home server and client must be connected to the same OpenVPN. Once connected to OpenVPN, they can ping each other using the VPN virtual IP addresses. You must allow [client-client](https://serverfault.com/questions/887266/how-to-allow-communications-with-client-to-client-on-openvpn-server) in OpenVPN server

Make sure that home servers are [persistently](https://openvpn.net/faq/how-can-i-ensure-that-the-vpn-stays-continuously-connected/) connected to OpenVPN