# OVPN Clients can't ping each other

Tags: openvpn

I hope that you can help me with my problem. I have configured an OpenVPN Server. Clients can connect and I can ping the clients from the virtual machine where the server is. But I want the clients to ping each other and for example see which devices are connected in the other clients network.

I have stumbled upon this post here [How to allow communications with client to client on OpenVPN Server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/887266/how-to-allow-communications-with-client-to-client-on-openvpn-server) but the solution with the firewall rules did not work.

My OpenVPN server configuration looks like this:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ../easy-rsa/pki/ca.crt
cert ../easy-rsa/pki/issued/server.crt
key ../easy-rsa/pki/private/server.key
dh ../easy-rsa/pki/dh.pem

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
client-config-dir ccd
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
explicit-exit-notify 1
mode server
tls-auth ta.key 0
key-direction 0
auth SHA256
tls-server
comp-lzo

#client1
route 10.8.3.0 255.255.255.0

#client2
route 10.8.4.0 255.255.255.0
```

I am open for suggestions - thanks in advance!

Comment: By "clients" do you mean the clients themselves or hosts in their LAN/site? What are the routes to `10.8.3.0/24` and `10.8.4.0/24` for?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my case the clients are hosts (routers). For example router 1 has the ip adress 10.8.3.1 and my laptop connected to the router has the ip adress 10.8.3.145. From here I want to ping the router 2 with the ip adress 10.8.4.1 or the device connected to the router 2 with the ip adress 10.8.4.100.
As I understand it, I need the route command in the server config so the clients use the specifc ip adresses.

Comment: Unless the two routers / clients are using the tun (that leads to this server) as their default route, you'll need to `push` route for their subnets to each other. Besides, you will need to setup `iroute` for the subnets so that traffics from one LAN can actually be led to the (router of) the other. The `route` directives you added might actually be optional (unless you rely on IP forwarding on the server host instead of `client-to-client`).